# Hybris - Deleting product from everywhere

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

We have a requirement to delete certain products from everywhere in hybris (including cart, orders, promotions) and all its references as well like Media, Category, Stocks, etc.

I found this one solution:

```
REMOVE Product [batchmode=true];itemType(code)[unique=true]
 ;Product;
```

I was wondering if just deleting the product, would remove all its references from hybris, or is there any better solution to do this.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing the product will remove references to it, but not the objects which are refering to it (like Media, Category, Stocks, etc.)

The only objects which will be deleted are those refered by attributes with the [partOf](https://wiki.hybris.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=141795383) modifier.

> A Part Of relationship between two classes extends an aggregation
>   relationship by ensuring that the lifecycle of the dependant object
>   (the part) is bound to the lifecycle of the parent object. When you
>   delete the parent object, all instances of its attribute types that
>   are marked as partOf will then be cascade-deleted.

Hybris doesn't know if a *Media* or a *Category* is no longer needed after a *Product* is removed. Therefore you must delete those objects explicitly.

Comment: In case, a product existing in an already placed order, would the product removal affect the order? If yes, what will happen to the total price, quantity of the order. For media, category, etc. I understand I have to separately delete the references of product from them.

Comment: Order prices and quantities are not calculated dynamically. They are stored in the Order or OrderEntries and are updated when needed. So they won't change on deletion of a product. Of course, you should test it, before deploying it.

Comment: @SanchitKhera: Does this answer your question?

Comment: In all my hybris experience I haven't come across (m)any projects that end up really deleting a product. 
Especially, once its been part of a placed order, removing a product would have all kinds of side effects/ things to take care of, the order entry of a placed order no longer references the product (error in a storefront's order history page), cancel/return/OMS would be affected (the whole OMS basically). 
Normally, I think projects using hybris tend to only mark a product as e.g. inactive, unapproved its approval status or other things to make it e.g. no longer show up in storefronts.

Comment: Thanks Sebastian and Christian!

Answer (score 0):

Removing product will remove only instances of product type, but not all data like media.

To remove from cart : it should inform user that product no longer available in store

For successfully placed orders : you should be able to display basic details of product with message as in cart [ :) :) But you should deliver if order is placed successfully and payment is received otherwise its a bad eCommerce impression]

For promotions : you should remove all promotions related to this product Or reconfigure according to business need.

Comment: Once order placed, nothing to be changed inside and should not be removed from order data.